# Deeply merge generic nested objects A and B while overriding B's duplicate properties with A's

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have two unknown (generic) nested objects that have a similar structure:

```js
const A = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: {
        func1: () => null,
      },
    },
  },
}
const B = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: {
        func2: () => null,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I'd like to create a type that merges them together so that both `func1` AND `func2` exist inside `one.two.three` but have `one`, `two`, and `three` only reference the properties of A.

Intersections get me close, but are not exactly what I need. For example, when I do this:

```js
const C: typeof A & typeof B = {}

C.one.two.three.func1() // Valid
C.one.two.three.func2() // Valid
```

Both functions are expected as values inside `three`, BUT each shared property refers back to both A and B whereas I need it to only refer back to A.

For example, if I want to jump to the definition of `three` from the C variable, my IDE will show two definitions I could jump to (A and B), but I only want Typescript to care about A and have my IDE jump to A since that would be the only option. But jumping to `func2` should still take me to where it's created in B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with ts-toolbelt's deep patch.

```js
import type { Object } from "ts-toolbelt"

type MergedTrpc = Object.Patch<A, B, "deep">
```